# SQL query to lambda expression or linq

Tags: sql

How can I convert the following query to a lambda expression

```
select * 
from Invoice_main 
where id not in 
    (select invoice_main_id from Invoice_payment_by_pay_method)
```

I could not find an alternative for 'not in'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using LINQ-to-SQL:

```
from inv in Invoice_main
where !(from m in Invoice_payment_by_pay_method select m.invoice_main_id).Contains(inv.id)
select inv
```

The !(...).Contains(...) is automatically converted by LINQ-to-SQL to a `NOT EXISTS` clause (note: this is more efficient than the `NOT IN` clause).

Other providers (i.e. not LINQ-to-SQL) may not support this rewrite of `.Contains` into `EXISTS` so this may not work for everything.

Comment: Hi, I'm using entitydatamodel. I dont know much about both entitydatamodel and linq to sql. But I think linq to sql will not work on entitydatamodel. when i use the suggested query its giving an error. its like - 'Could not find an implementation of the query pattern...'

Comment: So you are using Entity Framework. LINQ-to-Entities is much more restrictive than LINQ-to-SQL (my own opinion). You don't have an equivalent with LINQ-to-Entities.  You'll have to have two LINQ-to-Entities queries, one to select ID's from pay_method, the other one using an `Any` clause to exclude ID's from the first query.

Comment: LINQ-to-Entities for EF4 will support limited cases of IN clause: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/